# Powertop autotune error - Cannot load from file

Tags: powertop

I'm trying to perform --auto-tune in powertop, however I get the following error

> Cannot load from file /var/cache/powertop/saved_parameters.powertop

If I browse to that directory the file does exist.

I started by running --calibrate first, which completed okay.

Here is the full print out;

```
~ $ sudo powertop --auto-tune
modprobe cpufreq_stats failedLoaded 48 prior measurements
Cannot load from file /var/cache/powertop/saved_parameters.powertop
File will be loaded after taking minimum number of measurement(s) with battery only 
RAPL device for cpu 0
RAPL Using PowerCap Sysfs : Domain Mask f
RAPL device for cpu 0
RAPL Using PowerCap Sysfs : Domain Mask f
Devfreq not enabled
glob returned GLOB_ABORTED
Cannot load from file /var/cache/powertop/saved_parameters.powertop
File will be loaded after taking minimum number of measurement(s) with battery only 
To show power estimates do 333 measurement(s) connected to battery only
Leaving PowerTOP
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is normal. You see the explanation `File will be loaded after taking minimum number of measurement(s) with battery only`.

This warning will go away after some time.

Comment: Will it automatically be taking these measurements or do I need to keep re-running autotune?

Comment: I suggest running autotune after using the laptop on battery for some time.

Comment: @Pilot6 I am getting this error every day.

Answer (score 2):

Run `sudo powertop` for some time and the counter will reach 0